# How to manipulate elements with jquery so they match their css-Selector "nth-of-type"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a gallery containing images in a href that are filtered by javascript according to their class (`.cata`, `.catb`, `.catc`).

```
<div class="section galleryholder">
    <a href="images/trends1.jpg" class="eb cata"><img src="images/trends1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/trends2.jpg" class="eb catb"><img src="images/trends1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/trends3.jpg" class="eb cata"><img src="images/trends1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/trends4.jpg" class="eb catc"><img src="images/trends1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/trends5.jpg" class="eb catb"><img src="images/trends1.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

I've applied some styles via css, that display the different hrefs and the containing images in a grid according to the css-selector nth-of-type:

```
.eb{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:33.33333333%;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.eb:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    width:66.66666667%;
}

.eb:nth-of-type(6n+1), .eb:nth-of-type(6n+2), .eb:nth-of-type(6n+3){
    float:right;
}

.eb img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

At the moment I hide and display the hrefs in my gallery via jquery (with `.hide()` and `.show()` ). The problem is, that the nth-of-type-selector applied in css of course doesn't redraw the shown elements, because the elements aren't removed from the DOM, only hidden.

Since I want to be able to show the hidden elements again, I think removing the matched elements from the DOM wouldn't be good practice and I decided to toggle the class of the .eb-elements to a different class. But this wouldn't give me the desired result of the css counting the matched elements again and applying the appropriate styles neither.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or at least post some of the javascript so it can be clear as to what problems you are having with it

Comment: Have you tried [:nth-of-type() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean but you could maybe prefix class with element type and wrap hidden elements in other type element so `:nth-of-type(equation)` would still match

Comment: @A. Wolff: Sorry I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish... but from the way your code is written, and the example of the page you are writing, wouldn't it make more sense to use jQuery to add/remove a class to certain elements, rather than relying on the CSS?

```
$( ".eb:nth-of-type(3n+1)" ).addClass( "eb-wide" );
```

then set your class of:

```
.eb:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    width:66.66666667%;
}
```

to this instead:

```
.eb-wide {
    width:66.66666667%;
}
```

And if that doesn't work, you could simply write a loop in your JavaScript to loop through the visible elements and add/remove a class to them every time the triggers are clicked.  I think this would make more sense, since you are manipulating the elements with JS anyway, and would still give you the control of the having the CSS handle the design.

Comment: I only want minimal javascript-dependencies. The filter depends on js but for styling I would like to avoid it, if possible…

Comment: Technically you can avoid it... keep your styles as they are to make initial styles, and use my solution to add/remove new classes that are similar to your current ones.  All the JS does is add classes to elements, which would make up for the style issues on filter.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem was the following: I cloned the elements changed their class, wrapped them in a div and positioned the divs after the original elements. Then I removed the original elements from the dom. To show the elements again I unwrapped them and changed their class.

Comment: so much for "minimal javascript-dependencies"...

Comment: It's a js-solution yes but since the filter works with js there are no additional dependencies - the styling still relies solely on css.

Comment: You miss the point... my solution added no "dependencies" either.  It simply added or removed classes to your existing HTML elements.  Your code is cloning elements, wrapping them, deleting them, unwrapping them, and so forth...  Both our solutions rely on CSS to style the elements.  Your solution seems very complicated, mine adds/removes a class.  But so long as you got it working, it doesn't matter at this point!  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks man! My problem was a little bit more complicated than described above because when media-queries make the layout change everything seems to get a bit messy since I'm playing with floats and so on… to me now everything seems to work fine and doesn't get too complicated. Thanks for your effort – appreciate it!

Comment: Heres the final solution: http://www.derkeim.com/portfolio-der-keim-werbeagentur-ansbach-webdesign.php